# How to open windows forms in the same window

Tags: vb.net, mdi

Assuming I want to open Form B from Form A, I use the following code in form A:

```
FormB.Show()

Me.Close()
```

This results in form A's window closing and Form B's window opening. This is very disruptive, so is it possible to open form B in form A's window? I've read something about an MdiContainer, so I did the following already:

-Created a new Windows Form in Visual Studio, calling it MainForm and setting its isMdiContainer property to True.
-Used the following code when opening Windows Forms:

```
FormB.MdiParent = MainForm
FormB.Show()

Me.Close()
```

But this results in FormB not showing up at all.

How do I do this?

--EDIT--

Based on the below replies, it seems the general consensus is to exclude Me.Close(). I've done that, but it seems that the problem isn't `Me.Close()`, but `FormB.MdiParent = MainForm`. For some reason, whenever I include that line in FormB's Load function, FormB doesn't even show up at all.

Comment: _"But this results in FormB not showing up at all."_ It's because when you call `Me.Close()` which is a `FormA.Close()` method, your FormA (the MainForm of your application) automatically sends a message to FormB, ordering it to close aswell, even if you didn't write that code : `CloseReason.FormOwnerClosing`. Use Me.Hide() instead if you don't want your application to end prematurely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have 2 forms , lets say "MainForm and Form1"

In youre mainForm you add the code "Me.IsMdiContainer = True" in the form load event.
To set the MdiContainer to the form.

```
Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.IsMdiContainer = True
End Sub
```

And a button to open the second form.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form1.Show()
End Sub
```

Then in the form1 loadevent you add the code "Me.MdiParent = MainForm"

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.MdiParent = MainForm
End Sub
```

Then it works "and dont call me.close then you close the form."

Comment: @Wakka02 My code works.. make a new form in your project and then put the code Me.MdiParent = MainForm in the form load event."then open it" see what happens. Maybe somthing else is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I Think You Want to show Both Forms at a Time.  then for that Don't Use the `.Close()` Method for Form A. Well there's another thing IF you want, when  Form B is Called Form A can be Hide using its `.Hide()` Method. also you can do the same from the child Form using the main forms object to show main form and Hide the Child Form.

Answer (score 0):

From FormA, do something like:

```
FormB frmB = new FormB()
frmB.MdiParent = Me
frmB.Show()
```

Don't close the current form with `Me.Close()`!

Answer (score 0):

You can use panel `object` as `container` to your new `form`.